# How to use NOT IN statment in postgresql-rust

Tags: postgresql, rust

I am using the deadpool-postgres crate and actix-web in my application.

I am trying to do this:

```
 let client: Client = db_pool.get().await.unwrap();
 let mut interface_ids_to_keep :Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
 // adding some ids to interface_ids_to_keep
 client.execute("DELETE FROM interface WHERE host_id = $1 AND interface_id NOT IN $2", &[&host.host_id, &interface_ids_to_keep]).await.unwrap();
```

I always get the following sql error:

```
syntax error at or near "$2" at character 66
```

Seams like gets not replaced with the value (prepared statement style).

Do you have an idea how to use this feature?

Comment: You could try `NOT (interface_id = ANY($2))` where `$2` is `ToSql` an array of whatever type `interface_id` is. Often these simple array queries can have the same execution plan as their `IN` / `NOT IN` equivalents - but double check an `EXPLAIN` to be sure.

Comment: This works actually works. This is the output of explain.
any:
 Delete on interface  (cost=0.01..12.86 rows=1 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on interface  (cost=0.01..12.86 rows=1 width=6)
         Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (host_id = 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4)


in:
 Delete on interface  (cost=0.00..12.85 rows=1 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on interface  (cost=0.00..12.85 rows=1 width=6)
         Filter: ((interface_id <> 2) AND (host_id = 1))

Thanks, but the question remains why in is not working?

Comment: https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/issues/745

Comment: @MartinGallagher would you mind answering, then I would mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NOT (interface_id = ANY($2))` where `$2` is `ToSql` of a Vec / slice of whatever type `interface_id` is.

Often these simple array queries can have the same execution plan as their `IN` / `NOT IN` equivalents - but double check an `EXPLAIN` to be sure.